# Scaling the number of MenuItems in a React-JS Material UI Select DropDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am relatively new to front end UI development. Any timely assistance would be of great help. I am trying to populate a Select Dropdown which has about 60K options from which the user can Select any ONE Option. I tried rendering all the options t once and as expected the browser seems to be hogging the screen in trying to render the dropdown with all the options. I was wondering if there are any other component / architecture that I am supposed to use to be able to render select dropdowns with large number of options.

In the below code I am using a function generateDropDown to generate the 60K MenuItems.

**JSX Snippet**:

```
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant={variantType}>
                    <InputLabel id = "cc-bank-name">Credit Card Name</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      labelId="cc-bank-name-id"
                      id="cc-bank-name"
                      value={ccBank}
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, setCcBank)}
                      label="Credit Card Bank Name"
                    >
                      <MenuItem value="">
                        <em>None</em>
                      </MenuItem>
                      {generateDropDown('cc_banks')}
                    </Select>
                    <FormHelperText>Select the credit cards owned by the client</FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

explore this material UI component:
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

If you are fetching the options from the backend then I would recommend making an ajax request to the backend on each search query in this component's search field and populate those filtered options. In this way, you can fetch only relevant options rather than all at once.